# Terminal Command to find maximum allowed TCP/IP connection on a port in Apache server(CentOS)

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, tcpip, concurrency

Is there any terminal commands to check the maximum allowed number of concurrent TCP/IP connections can be done in Apache server with CentOS??

Answer (score 1):

There is no a single command.

There are configurable limits within Apache httpd itself that govern the number of allowed concurrent incoming TCP connections such as the [`MaxRequestWorkers <number>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) directive and/or depending on the selected MPM others, such as `ListenBacklog` , `ServerLimit` and `ThreadsPerChild`.

From the OS level each TCP/IP connection consumes a file descriptor and the number of open file descriptors is both finite and limited.
Limits for Apache httpd are typically set/read with `ulimit -n` when apache httpd is started or for instance from `/etc/security/limits.conf`.
The overall OS limit is a kenrel tuneable and set/read with: `sysctl fs.nr_open` and of interest can also be `sysctl net.core.somaxconn`.

If you're using a software firewall, i.e. netfiler/iptables/firewalld etc. you may need to look at `sysctl net.nf_conntrack_max` as well.